# TFDTable edit fails with Firebird 2.5.7 not 2.5.3

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

This code:

```
FDConnection.Open;      // Design time TFDConnection; default settings
TabelGrid.Close;        // TDFTable connected to TFDConnection; default settings
TabelGrid.TableName := 'TT_ACT';
TabelGrid.Open;
TabelGrid.Edit;
TabelGrid.FieldByName('TT_NAME').AsString := TabelGrid.FieldByName('TT_NAME').AsString + '*';
TabelGrid.Post;
```

fails with

```
[FireDAC][Phys][IB]-312 Exact update affected [0] rows, while [1] was requested
```

when Firebird 2.5.7 is installed, **not** when Firebird 2.5.3 is installed.

Call stack:

[image]

Conditions:

- The `TFDConnection` points to a local .GDB file, driverID IB or FB, default `sysdba` password, all default settings. `TFDPhysIBDriverLink` or `TFDPhysFBDriverLink` present.
- Delphi Tokyo 10.2.3 Win32 code, Windows 7
- Firebird installed with option to put gds32.dll in System32; **no** spurious Firebird DLLs lying around
- Interbase not present on system

The table has 3 indices:

```
TT_I0_ACT                TT_ACT_ID                Primary
TT_I1_ACT                TT_PARENT_ID             
TT_I2_ACT                TT_FROMDATE
```

I've fumbled with settings, especially changing the default `UpdateOptions.UpdateMode`s from `UpWhereKeyOnly` to `UpWhereChanged` or `UpWhereAll`, but no results so far.

What can be going on; what else can I investigate?

We distribute Firebird 2.5.3 with our app, but I'm afraid it will fail when clients already have a later version (as we found out when one of our developers upgraded FB).

Additional research:

The query that I see in `TFDPhysCommandAsyncExecute.Execute` (`FireDAC.Phys.pas`) for both versions is (with the default `UpWhereKey` update mode):

```
UPDATE TT_ACT SET TT_NAME = :NEW_TT_NAME WHERE RDB$DB_KEY = :OLD_DB_KEY
```

(actually, all `FCommand` properties show identical in the inspector).

I've looked through the [Firebird 2.5.x. release notes](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/2_5/rlsnotes25.html) and saw only one in 2.5.6 that is somewhat related:

[The number of affected rows was reported incorrectly for an update against a view created WITH CHECK OPTION](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-4870)

I'm not sure this applies because it's about views. Setting `UpdateOptions.CountUpdatedOptions` to false makes no difference.

There's nothing in the 2.5.8 fixes list that indicates that a relevant bug was introduced in versions 2.5.4-2.5.7.

---

I have traced the FireDAC code to the point where execution differs in 2.5.3 and 2.5.7 but that ends with an interface method that I cannot trace:

```
TFDTable.InternalPost
TFDDataSet.InternalPost
TFDAdaptedDataSet.DoProcessUpdateRequest(arUpdate
TFDCustomTableAdapter.Update
TFDCustomTableAdapter.UpdateAdapterCmds(const ACmds: array of TFDActionRequest);
  ACmds contains (arUpdate, arFetchRow)
back to TFDCustomTableAdapter.Update  
TFDDAptTableAdapter.Update
TFDDAptTableAdapter.ProcessUpdate
  In the 'build command if required' part
  oCmd.SQLText := 'UPDATE TT_ACT'#$A'SET TT_NAME = ?'#$A'WHERE RDB$DB_KEY = ?'  
  ProcessRequest 
in TFDDAptTableAdapter.ProcessRequest
  SetParamsFromRow(ACommand.Params, ARow);
    AParams.Count=2: NEW_TT_NAME and OLD_DB_KEY. OLD_DB_KEY value is 0 in both cases
  then
  ACommand.Execute;
TFDPhysCommand.Execute    
  ExecuteTask
TFDPhysCommand.ExecuteTask
  FExecutor.Run
TFDStanAsyncExecutor.Run;
TFDStanAsyncExecutor.ExecuteOperation
FOperationIntf.Execute;
TFDPhysCommandAsyncExecute.Execute
TFDPhysCommand.ExecuteBase
FExecutor.Launched; -> Interface, cannot trace
Process_SingleRow  
Process_HandleSystemFailure
InternalExecute   -> Interface, cannot trace
```

This last call returns with var parameter ACount to 1 for 2.5.3, and 0 for 2.5.7

The GetRowCounts function returns

```
FRowsUpdated,FRowsDeleted,FRowsSelected,FRowsInserted: 1 0 1 0 in 2.5.3
FRowsUpdated,FRowsDeleted,FRowsSelected,FRowsInserted: 0 0 0 0 in 2.5.7
```

Comment: is there a way you can explicitly key the primary key columns into the table component? it seems the `UPDATE` message sent to server (you did not show it) had problematic `WHERE` part which kept visible those very "0 rows" /// BTW, 2.5.8 is the last in the line, not 2.5.7

Comment: if you do commit the transaction, disconnect and reconnect, would the row in the database be really changed or not? (also, is it a one-singleton-row table that you do not care which row you do change?)

Comment: If the data is not persisted, you may want to explicitly put primary key fields into `UpdateOptions.KeyFields` and switch the dataset to using those instead of `RDB$DBKEY` - http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/firedac/Unique_Identifying_Fields.html

Comment: Inspect what's happening inside the `TIBStatement.GetRowCounts` method.

Comment: What happens if you try with Firebird 2.5.8?

Comment: @Victoria The info returned from GetSQLInfo(isc_info_sql_records, is all 0 for 4 returns of iCount. The buff array is (23, 29, 0, 15, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 16, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 13, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 14, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ....

Comment: @Arioch'The The string field is *not* updated in a transaction, regardless of what record I take

Comment: Could you step through the `TFDDAptTableAdapter.SetParamsFromRow` method when `oPar.FName` will be `OLD_DB_KEY`? Specifically, if such column will be found in the internal storage (if yes, you can also check the value of the key there, e.g. by watch `Integer(pBuff^)` when the data are retrieved from the storage).

Comment: You should be using fbclient.dll not GDS32.dll.

Comment: @nolaspeaker, installer only installs fbclient.dll as GDS32.dll in this case.

Comment: compare execution paths and variable values when application works okay with 2.5.3. and when it fails with 2.5.8 - there should be a point where values and/or execution paths start to diverge. // Also try to make FireDAC use PK not DB_KEY

Comment: @Arioch'The Code trace added, ends in interface call that I cannot follow.

Comment: @Victoria SetParamsFromRow has OLD_DB_KEY with value 0 in both cases. Code trace added.

Comment: You can trace interface method. Do Trace Into (F7) and be patient (because there might be some system interface reference stuff you jump into).

Comment: `OLD_DB_KEY value is 0 in both cases` hard to believe. `SetParamsFromRow` perhaps should had populated them...

Comment: "system reference stuff" can be probably made seen by "Use Debug DCUs" - however if FireDAC drivers are DLLs with no debug info - it would not help